# Setting up deployment Python project to Azure Web App Failed

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines, webdeploy

I'm having trouble set up deployment python project to the Azure Web App on Linux.

I choose Azure Repo -> Azure Pipelines (Preview) -> (Organization, Project, Repo, Branche) at the deployment center in azure portal.

After clicking 'Finish' I received a notification 'Failed to set up deployment'.

I don't know what's wrong. I don't know how I can troubleshooting them.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: What method are you using to deploy? Git/FTP?

Comment: I don't have Azure Repo in any of my Azure Web App services menus. I have deployment center, but it tracks each deployment with a UUID when it gets pushed through git. There was minimal set up as all I had to do was set up a username and password to deploy. Then, I selected git in the portal. Check out this link for more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python

Comment: Is there a CLI command you can use to deploy, in that case you can share the logs ?

Comment: I use Azure Repo -> Azure Pipelines because I want set up continue integration after pull merge into master. (when I use local git and push into git in the portal, its ok)